# Tire modification in cycles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, spring

If springs were fitted to the ridges in the tire of a cycle, would it make the cycle ride more 'easier' (considering only flat terrain)?

[image]

Kind of like in the above meme? What would be the favorable range for the springs' coefficient?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Look up [tweel](https://tweel.michelinman.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It would make it more **difficult** as the springs will **slide** on the surface as they have very **small contact** with the surface and also **low friction coefficient**

Comment: Wouldn't there also be an equal torque in the direction of rotation (from springs which are leaving contact with the ground)? The reverse and forward torques would cancel out (mostly). I don't think the flat tyre is acting like a spring.

Comment: @sammygerbil yes there would be but not equal think of the case of flat tyre then it should also have a torque and its antitorque

Comment: then why is it difficult in that case while driving

Comment: Tyres are very spring-like when fully inflated but much less so when they are under inflated or flat. In the former case the deformation is small, elastic and symmetrical so that forward and reverse torques balance. In the latter case the deformation is large so the non-elastic loss (hysteresis) is greater; and the deformation is not symmetrical, more rubber is squeezed into the leading edge of the wheel so the forward and reverse torques are very different.

Comment: @sammygerbil I have made another thought on it please check it out

Comment: @sammygerbil your point was a valid point but our weight is also shifted on one of the sides of the spring

Comment: So that can also be used for explanation

Comment: The weight of the bicycle frame and rider acts downwards through the points where the axle joins the wheel. Good point about the springs not having much friction.